# Best way to learn MySql

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, database

i want to learn mysql. what i do for learn it.
Currently i Read books on MySql. any other way for learn it

Comment: I hope you are doing more than _just_ reading the books... are you actually writing code that uses MySQL?

Comment: The documentation on the MySQL website is a pretty good place to start,  but can you be more specific about what you want to do? Do you want to learn how to administer it? Write queries against it? Efficiently lay out databases?

Comment: I think the best way is starting to learn SQL and I don't think that MySQL is the better way for this.

Answer (score 5):

Just start using it. Build some stuff, play with it, you will run into problems eventually. And then you can use your books (and internet) to solve them.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this site will give you some good execises. Search some of the questions (even if answered) and see if you can follow what eh answers do. See if you can get to the answer without looking ( Dont cheat **X-)** ).

Ask if you cant find the solution, but dig in, try some of the "LIVe" examples.

Comment: Agreed - great place to pick up small tasks, often with sample data to much around with.

Answer (score 0):

Think about some problem domain like a library for example.  It will contain books, periodicals, cds, dvds, etc.  It will have certain actions like taking out a book, returning a book, issuing library cards, etc.  Model this in the database of your choice, and write the sql to extract as much of this information as possible:  things like who has overdue books, when will the persons library card expire, how many items are catalogued as comp-sci, etc.  You get the idea.

After completing this exercise you will know more sql than most developers !